# How to hide Navigation properties when creating JSON response using EF 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4

I am developing a Web Services application, and when I get from my EF model - for example a list of my "User" object - I get the fields of my table PLUS the Foreign Keys, etc?

Does any know how to avoid these? I have been trying to modify the poco template but without luck.

```
     namespace JOhn.DataAccess
{
    [Serializable()]
    [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
    public class CustomEntityObject : EntityObject
    {
        //[DataMember]
        [Browsable(false)]
        [XmlIgnore]
        [SoapIgnore]
        public new EntityKey EntityKey { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A common solution is to use the DTO ("Data Transfer Object") pattern.

Define a new class called `UserDto` which contains just the fields you want to expose over your API, then copy the values from your `User` entity object to a `UserDto` instance.

Packages like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) can be used to avoid writing the value copying code.

Comment: Hi Ross, thanks for you answer, all my objects are based on an Custom Entity Object...so i think I can edit the Custom Edit Object...but I can't figure out how....the only solution that worked easy is removing [datamember] from each unwanted property of each Object...is there anyway to do this at once for all objects? I have declared...this is the Custom Entity: I have added that above.

Answer (score 1):

There is a

```
[ScriptIgnore]
```

Attribute as well, it works well with Microsoft's default JavaScript Serializer.

```
namespace AutoFX.DataAccess
{
  [Serializable()]
  [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
  public class CustomEntityObject : EntityObject
  {
    //[DataMember]
    [Browsable(false)]
    [XmlIgnore]
    [SoapIgnore]
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public new EntityKey EntityKey { get; set; }
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try creating a model class and bind the data of the user object using this model. This will help to overcome the dependencies ..

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it without creating DTO's is to use [JSON.Net in your MVC Application](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2008/10/16/asp-net-mvc-and-json-net.aspx).  Then your object could look like:

```
namespace John.DataAccess
{
  [Serializable()]
  [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
  public class CustomEntityObject : EntityObject
  {
    //[DataMember]
    [Browsable(false)]
    [XmlIgnore]
    [SoapIgnore]
    [JsonIgnore]
    public new EntityKey EntityKey { get; set; }
  }
```

}